# I have tried to connect android and wamp for login interface for my app. I not getting the output

Tags: android, mysql, wampserver

I am doing an android app called phone book. faculty contacts are saved in database in local host. The contacts have to display only if user gives valid password. I have written program for log in interface. which takes  input(password) from user if  password is correct it has to display "log in successful" else "failed".
I am getting run time error in my code. please help me out.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    etUsn=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
    login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    login.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void onClick(View v)
{   
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();   
    httppost= new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/log.php");
    Usn=etUsn.getText().toString();
    try
    {
        namevaluepair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Usn",Usn));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namevaluepair));
        response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
        {
            entity=response.getEntity();
            if(entity!=null)
            {
                InputStream instream=entity.getContent();
               JSONObject jsonResponse=new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));
                String retUsn;
                retUsn =jsonResponse.getString("usn");//table field
                if(Usn.equals(retUsn))
                {
                    SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("login details", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor spedit= sp.edit();
                    spedit.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid usn", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
       }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "connection error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what Type of Error you are getting. Put your logCat error here.

I think there is problem in in your ***onClick(View View )*** method . please check in your ***login.xml*** that you put `android:onClick = 'onClick'` tag in your login button.